# Adjust gap in between x-axis and label

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my D3 chart, I changed the `tickSize` to `0`. As a result the gap between the axis and the label is almost nil. How do I adjust this gap so as to look decent?

D3 x-axis code:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickSize(0,0);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5stce/16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increased the tick size.

And targeted the element using this `.tick line` and used the css property `display: none;`.

[**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/5stce/17/)

Comment: One follow-up question you may like to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874959/how-to-set-width-to-x-axis-label