# How to set width to x-axis label?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

If the x-axis label is long, it is getting overlapper on the next label [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/5stce/20/). How do I set a width to it so that it appears as in the snapshot below?

[image]

x-axis code:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickSize(10,10);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/5stce/20/)

Comment: Try [**`This`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770344/truncate-text-in-d3).

Comment: @UnknownUser: It did not work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/5stce/21/ What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't do the exact thing what's there in the image.

But i found [<kbd>**this**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/5stce/22/) from this [<kbd>**link**</kbd>](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).

Wrapping the `x` axis labels using a custom function.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Looks good! How do I add the function so that it takes the substring and appends `...` in there?

Comment: That's the thing i couldn't find out. I guess you actually don't need to take sub string. It'll wrap the entire text to be visible at any length. And that's more convenient than the sub string where the users see the entire label nice and clean.

Comment: Increase the height of the `svg`. Actually the text is getting wrapped but the height of svg is not enough to display it entirely. `.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 20)`. Try adding +20.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this qiestion of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087358/tooltip-fetching-incorrect-data