# Tooltip fetching incorrect data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Please refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/5stce/40/

The data that the tooltip is fetching is incorrect. How do I fix it?

Relevant part of the code:

```
episode.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 15)
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
.on("mouseover", function(d) {      
    tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);      
    tooltip.html("YES: " + Number(d.y1*100) + "%<br/>NO: " + Number(d.y0*100) + "%")  
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
})                  
.on("mouseout", function(d) {       
    tooltip.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried but can't make it with your code. so i used another way to Find Percentages if you like use it.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5stce/49/)

```
   var x=Number($(this).attr("height"))/45;
   if($(this).css("fill")=="rgb(255, 51, 50)"){
   tooltip.html("YES: " + Number((10-x)*10) + "%<br/>NO: " + Number(x*10) + "%")
    }
   else
   {
    tooltip.html("YES: " + Number((x)*10) + "%<br/>NO: " + Number(10-x)*10 + "%")
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :) Can you help me with this follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089076/how-do-i-style-the-bars-like-this ?