# How do I style the bars like this?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As of now, I have the background bars styled [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/64/).

How do I change it so as to look like this, with the tiny white stripes:

[image]

Code:

```
defs = svg.append('svg:defs');

defs
.append('svg:pattern')
.attr('id', 'stripe_bg')
.attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
.attr('width', '8')
.attr('height', '8')
.append('svg:image')
.attr('xlink:href', 'http://snag.gy/vLMrD.jpg')
.attr('x', 0)
.attr('y', 0)
.attr('width', 8)
.attr('height', 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/NNgaT/

The change was in how the path is being generated:

```
.attr('d', function (d, i) {
    // ...     
    return [ "M", [ (xPos - ((i === 0) ? -1 : 1 ) * flareRadius), height],
           // ...
            [(xPos + barWidth + ((i === data.length - 1) ? -1 : 1) * flareRadius), height],
            "Z"
           ].join(" ");
}
```

So for the first and last bars, I have inverted the movement of the path on the left and right side respectively.

Comment: How do I match the radius of *that* corner with that on the top? Also, how do I get the white stripes on the backbround bar?